# Node.js and aws credentials error

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, electron

i'm trying to develop an electron.js app to upload data to aws s3, but i have a problem while trying to load my credentials from a json file. The JSON file looks like that:

```
{ "accessKeyId": "my access key", "secretAccessKey": "my secret", "region": "eu-west-1" }
```

and the code that load the json file:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');

/*
I tried both to load from 'path' string and loading './accounts.json'
*/

var path = process.cwd() + '/accounts.json';
console.log(path);
AWS.config.loadFromPath(path);

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    else {
        for (var index in data.Buckets) {
            var bucket = data.Buckets[index];
            console.log("Bucket: ", bucket.Name);
        }
    }
});
```

The error is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of null
```

**EDIT**

I also tried providing absolute folder (e.g.: '/home/user/project/file.json'), but it doesn't work, it only works hard coding the credentials, like this:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "access key id",
    secretAccessKey: "secret access key",
    "region": "eu-west-1"
});
```

Comment: From first glance your code seems OK. maybe try to print contents of the file in 'path' variable first to see if your path is correct?

Comment: I'be already printed out the content of path and that's ok, but It doesn't work at all

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, but I recommend assigning an IAM_role to your EC2 instance (assuming your code runs on EC2) and avoid the hassles and also related decreased security by using access keys and secrets. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: I have executed the same code and it works for me. Please check whether the location of the credentials file is correct

Comment: I also tried it in a tmp folder with only the json and javascript file and it works, but in electron it doesn't work with providing credentials in a json file, nor taking them from the default directory (.aws/credentials). Is maybe the package.json file giving me problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a sample code that I have tested and it works.
Link to drone.io output (as well as the source code).
https://drone.io/github.com/ttwd80/electron-aws/27

My change was that I did not use this:

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath(path);
```

I used this:
load the json file to make it an object
and update the credentials using AWS.config.update

```
const keys = require(__dirname + '/keys.json');
AWS.config.update({"accessKeyId": keys.awsAccessKey, "secretAccessKey": keys.awsSecretKey, "region": keys.region});
```

Answer (score -1):

Electron has some issues that doesn't make it work properly with aws sdk