# Getting 'str.indexOf is not a function' error when trying to S3.getSignedUrl()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While trying to get a signed URL for a `getObject` I am getting the following error from the `aws-sdk` library:

```
<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:983
      return str && str.indexOf('arn:') === 0 && str.split(':').length >= 6;
                        ^

TypeError: str.indexOf is not a function
    at Object.validateARN [as validate] (<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:983:25)
    at features.constructor.hasBucketInParams [as isAccessPointApplicable] (<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:180:2
3)
    at features.constructor.setupRequestListeners (<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:126:14)
    at features.constructor.addAllRequestListeners (<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\service.js:276:10)
    at features.constructor.makeRequest (<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\service.js:203:10)
    at features.constructor.getSignedUrl (<proj-dir>\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:1026:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<proj-dir>\s3-test.js:101:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
```

Other S3 calls (like `listBuckets`) are working fine. Here's my test file:

```
const S3 = require('./utils/s3Util');
const C = require('./utils/constants');
const _ = require('lodash');

// other code...

S3.svc.getSignedUrl('getObject', { Bucket: C.S3_BUCKET, Key: 'TestFrequencyCount.java', Expires: 60 }).promise()
    .then(retVal => {
        console.log("Return value:", retVal);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error::", err);
    });
```

The `s3Util.js` file:

```
const C = require('./constants');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const keys = require("../config/aws-config.json");

// AWS.config.update(keys);

const s3 = new AWS.S3({...keys, apiVersion: C.S3_API_VER, signatureVersion: 'v4' });

module.exports = Object.freeze({
    svc: s3,
});
```

I was using `aws-sdk` version 2.610.0, then updated that to 2.621.0, but the problem remains.

Even tried by changing the way I was loading the AWS account credentials (will use an IAM user once I have things figured out) based on a combination of [this note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) from AWS SDK documentation:

> Note: You must ensure that you have static or previously resolved
> credentials if you call this method synchronously (with no callback),
> otherwise it may not properly sign the request. If you cannot
> guarantee this (you are using an asynchronous credential provider,
> i.e., EC2 IAM roles), you should always call this method with an
> asynchronous callback.

and the solution given at [Node.js and aws credentials error - json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37507464/) (which suggested not using `AWS.config.loadFromPath(path)` but instead loading the parameters directly through `AWS.config.update(...)`), but to no avail.

In deseparation I tried the callback version as well, but as expected it gave the same result:

```
S3.svc.getSignedUrl('getObject', { Bucket: C.S3_BUCKET, Key: 'TestFrequencyCount.java', Expires: 60 }, (err, retVal) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error::", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Return value:", retVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was with the definition of `C.S3_BUCKET`: it should have been used instead as: `C.S3_BUCKET[process.env.NODE_ENV]`.

Answer (score 1):

`str` variable is probably an object, not a string or array, so `indexOf` method cannot be applied to it. Use console.log(str) to confirm this.

Comment: try "typeof variable". make sure you are getting string.

Comment: That line is not in my code, it's in aws-sdk's code.